# Насколько приемлемо хранить информацию о пути к файлу в БД?

Tags: база-данных, файловая-система

К примеру, есть таблица "Сварочные аппараты", которая характеризует аппарат по названию, цвету, запаху и т.д., к аппарату на странице с описанием должна быть приложена документация - набор файлов doc, pdf, jpg с соответствующими на них ссылками. Так вот, насколько приемлемо создание нечто вроде таблицы "файлы", в которой будут хранится названия файлов, связанных отношением с соответствующими аппаратами? Просто тогда возникает проблема синхронизации записей в БД и содержимого ФС.

Comment: А другого пути в общем то нет. Ну т.е. есть конечно, можно в самой БД хранить файлы, но imho заморочек больше. Пока они вне БД их можно быстро каким нибудь ngix раздавать. И да, конечно проблемы есть, возможно потребуются обслуживающие скрипты ищущие несоответствия. В одной системе у меня подобные файлы на диске называются на основе ID объекта и в БД вообще не хранится путь, он вычисляется и проверяется наличие файла, если есть клиенту отдается ссылка, если нет - показывается загрушка

Comment: Храните что хотите. Проблемы с синхронизацией может будут, а может быть нет. Никому не известно, что Вы собираетесь делать с этой базой и этими файлами